# Endogenous instruments in IV 2SLS regression in Stata

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables

If I am looking at an `ivreg2` equation where:

```
ivreg2 y1 x2 x3 x4 (x1 = x5 x6)
```

and I know that `x5` and `x6` are endogenous variables (i.e. they are motivated by latent, unmeasurable characteristics) and there are no other viable alternatives, does IV 2sls work?  Is it biased? Inconsistent?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Am i missing something obvious, or do you not have any instrumental variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the prime assumptions of instrumental variables is the *exclusion restriction*---essentially, it states that the instrument(s) must be exogenous and not directly related to your outcome $y$ (they can only impact $y$ indirectly by changing your endogenous variable $x_1$). If you don't have any exogenous variables, then you don't have any candidates for instruments. As a result, IV will not deliver unbiased or consistent results.